# Getting Docker Windows Containers to start automatically on reboot

Tags: docker-for-windows

My OS is Windows 10 and I am running Docker version 17.06.0-ce-win19.  I am trying to set up a container so that it will restart automatically on reboot.

When I use the command:
docker run -it  microsoft/nanoserver --restart=always

I’m getting the following error:

docker: Error response from daemon: container 35046c88d2564523464ecabc4d48eb0550115e33acb25b0555224e7c43d21e74 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"ApplicationName":"","CommandLine":"--restart=always","User":"","WorkingDirectory":"C:\","Environment":{},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":false,"ConsoleSize":[30,120]}.

whereas if I leave out the 
--restart=always
everything works fine.

Is there something else I need to do to get --restart options working on Windows?

Comment: It follows you command, it has to prepend it

Comment: Yep that was the problem. docker run  --restart=always -it microsoft/nanoserver

Comment: Please accept my answer below

Comment: That got me over that error, but when I reboot the machine, the container is not running. What else do I need to do?

Comment: When I do a docker inspect the settings are there with the container   "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supposed on Windows 10 since I believe it does not have proper docker service running for this functionality to exist. Check if it works on Windows 2016 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters shall be coming before image:tag in CLI